# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac1{s-\lambda}$ is $e^{\lambda t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I got that the inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{s-\lambda}$ is $e^{\lambda t}$. Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. The inverse Laplace transform is
$$
\mathcal{L}\{F(s)\} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds.
$$
In your problem, we have that $F(s) = \frac{1}{s-\lambda}$ so we have a simple pole in the $s$ plane at $s = \lambda$.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s-\lambda}ds\\
&= \sum\text{Res}\\
&= \lim_{s\to\lambda}(s-\lambda)\frac{e^{st}}{s-\lambda}\\
&= e^{t\lambda}
\end{align}
as you have found.